# How to get the list of the authenticated users?

Tags: django, authentication

I would like to display the list of the authenticated users.

On the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

> class models.User
>   is_authenticated()¶
>       Always returns True. This is a way to tell if the user has been authenticated. ...

You can know on the template side is the **current** User is authenticated or not:

> {% if user.is_authenticated %}
>          {% endif %}

But I didn't found the way the get the list of the authenticated users.

Any idea?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Going along with rz's answer, you could query the `Session` model for non-expired sessions, then turn the session data into users.  Once you've got that you could turn it into a template tag which could render the list on any given page.

(This is all untested, but hopefully will be close to working).

Fetch all the logged in users...

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.utils import timezone

def get_all_logged_in_users():
    # Query all non-expired sessions
    # use timezone.now() instead of datetime.now() in latest versions of Django
    sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    uid_list = []

    # Build a list of user ids from that query
    for session in sessions:
        data = session.get_decoded()
        uid_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))

    # Query all logged in users based on id list
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=uid_list)
```

Using this, you can make a simple inclusion template tag...

```
from django import template
from wherever import get_all_logged_in_users
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('templatetags/logged_in_user_list.html')
def render_logged_in_user_list():
    return { 'users': get_all_logged_in_users() }
```

**logged_in_user_list.html**

```
{% if users %}
<ul class="user-list">
    {% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Then in your main page you can simply use it where you like...

```
{% load your_library_name %}
{% render_logged_in_user_list %}
```

**EDIT**

For those talking about the 2-week persistent issue, I'm assuming that anyone wanting to have an "active users" type of listing will be making use of the [`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions) setting, though I recognize this isn't always the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what i was looking for.

Gerald

Comment: Um, just so you know "non-expired sessions" will give you everyone who has been logged in for *two weeks*…  Look at django-tracking instead if you would like currently active users.

Comment: same comment as @jonwd7.  It is probably better to check for last_login or some more sophisticated filtering. 2 weeks hardly counts as "currently"

Comment: You could probably throw together some middleware that sets a session variable to timestamp the most recent request for all users and then filter on those less than 5 minutes old. Then the above solution would work pretty well.

Comment: I was using the `get_all_logged_in_users` to get active users but it stops working a few days ago?  using `Python(2.7)` and `Django(1.11)`.

Answer (score 8):

Most reliable solution would only be the something you store when user logs in or logs out. I saw this solution and i think its worth sharing.

### models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in, user_logged_out

class LoggedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def login_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        LoggedUser(user=user).save()

    def logout_user(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
        try:
            u = LoggedUser.objects.get(user=user)
            u.delete()
        except LoggedUser.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    user_logged_in.connect(login_user)
    user_logged_out.connect(logout_user)
```

### views.py

```
logged_users = LoggedUser.objects.all().order_by('username')
```

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and it works pretty good, even better than the accepted answer because in some cases it didn't detected when users log-out (but I have modified the User class). About your solution, to get the real logged_users I had to do: `logged_users=[user.user for user in LoggedUser.objects.all()]`

Comment: NameError: name 'user_logged_in' is not defined

Comment: Its a django signal, i have updated the answer to include the import. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds similiar with this solution, you can create a custom middleware to do it. I found awesome [`OnlineNowMiddleware`](https://gist.github.com/agusmakmun/c0c81ee21245578b1f13c003d1def401) here.

Where you will get these;

1. `{{ request.online_now }}` => display all list of online users.
2. `{{ request.online_now_ids }}` => display all online user ids.
3. `{{ request.online_now.count }}` => display total online users.

**How to set up?**

Create file `middleware.py` where location of `settings.py` has been saved, eg:

```
projectname/projectname/__init__.py
projectname/projectname/middleware.py
projectname/projectname/settings.py
```

Then following this lines;

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

ONLINE_THRESHOLD = getattr(settings, 'ONLINE_THRESHOLD', 60 * 15)
ONLINE_MAX = getattr(settings, 'ONLINE_MAX', 50)


def get_online_now(self):
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=self.online_now_ids or [])


class OnlineNowMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    Maintains a list of users who have interacted with the website recently.
    Their user IDs are available as ``online_now_ids`` on the request object,
    and their corresponding users are available (lazily) as the
    ``online_now`` property on the request object.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        # First get the index
        uids = cache.get('online-now', [])

        # Perform the multiget on the individual online uid keys
        online_keys = ['online-%s' % (u,) for u in uids]
        fresh = cache.get_many(online_keys).keys()
        online_now_ids = [int(k.replace('online-', '')) for k in fresh]

        # If the user is authenticated, add their id to the list
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            uid = request.user.id
            # If their uid is already in the list, we want to bump it
            # to the top, so we remove the earlier entry.
            if uid in online_now_ids:
                online_now_ids.remove(uid)
            online_now_ids.append(uid)
            if len(online_now_ids) > ONLINE_MAX:
                del online_now_ids[0]

        # Attach our modifications to the request object
        request.__class__.online_now_ids = online_now_ids
        request.__class__.online_now = property(get_online_now)

        # Set the new cache
        cache.set('online-%s' % (request.user.pk,), True, ONLINE_THRESHOLD)
        cache.set('online-now', online_now_ids, ONLINE_THRESHOLD)
```

Finally update your `MIDDLEWARE` inside file of `projectname/projectname/settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    ....
    # Custom middleware
    'projectname.middleware.OnlineNowMiddleware',
]
```

For other condition, you can also check the current user is online or not with:

```
{% if request.user in request.online_now %}
    {# do stuff #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Any idea how to modify this so that is removes users from online_now when they log out ?

Comment: @PaddyPopeye by default, it handled with `ONLINE_THRESHOLD`. So, after users sign out for `60 * 15` => 15 minutes automaticaly deleted from `online_now`.

Comment: thks for the answer. but the problem with the code is that even though ONLINE_THRESHOLD handles this, it is not reflected on the page. Only after the page is refreshed manually do you see that a user has logged out.. any suggestions

Comment: @PaddyPopeye If what you need is realtime method, perhaps you can handle it with ajax post inside `setInterval`. eg: https://pastebin.com/3xVFpJiB

Comment: this solution looks good, I am thinking about what could be the drawbacks of this solution? Also, the accepted answer involves querying the session model, which is a db hit. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I have a problem with that solution. I opened 2 sessions: one in the normal tab and another one in incognito mode. I wait over 15 mins and the user still remains online. Any fix for that?

Comment: What is the purpose of ```ONLINE_MAX = getattr(settings, 'ONLINE_MAX', 50)```? It only counts 50 users?

Comment: @There yes, meanwhile you can remove it methods if needed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy, built-in way to do what you want that I know of.  I'd try a combination of expiring sessions and filtering on last_login.  Maybe even write a custom manager for that.