# How do I check if a 'different' user is logged in in django?

Tags: django, django-users

Every where I look for 'checking if user is logged in' directs me to checking if the currently logged in user is logged in. If I have a list of friends, and I want to see who in that list is logged in. How can I check that?

I've tried 'user.is_authenticated()' on the friends, but it always comes back as 'True'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this data from sessions table.

Check this question [How to get the list of the authenticated users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723052/how-to-get-the-list-of-the-authenticated-users)

Comment: Oh geesus, that doesn't look easy at all. Thanks though!