# is_authenticated returns True for logged out user

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm writing a server app using Django, Django REST framework, Django-rest-auth and Django-allauth. I have a method that's used to pass messages between users, and this should only happen when the receiver is logged in.

However, it seems that the user object's `is_authenticated()` method returns True even though the user has logged out (called `rest-auth/logout/`, which should in turn call Django's logout). What could cause this? Is there something I've missed here?

Here's the code I have:

```
class SendMessage(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        m = self.request.data['msg']
        targetUser = User.objects.get(pk = self.request.data['user'])

        if targetUser.is_authenticated():
            # Send message
        else:
            # Don't send message
```

Comment: Are there 2 users? One sender and one receiver? When sender performs some action, you wish to send a message to receiver depending on whether the receiver is logged in or not? Is this the scenario?

Comment: @AnimeshSharma Yes, exactly. There's two users, and I want to check if they both are authenticated (logged in). The 'current user' is checked by the permissions, and now I'm trying to check the other one (the targetUser).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the is_authenticated() method always returns true.

```
 def is_authenticated(self):
    """
    Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
    authenticated in templates.
    """
    return True
```

It is meant to discern between a User instance and an AnonymousUser instance, which is what the User is set as when they do not pass authentication.

Comment: I stumbled upon the very same piece of code just as you posted your answer. However, the question remains: how do I check if the `targetUser` is authenticated or not?

Comment: How can they not be authenticated? If the current user is not anonymous, they are authenticated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There's two users involved, the current user and the target user. I want to check if the target user is authenticated (i.e. logged in).

Comment: @DanielRoseman I chose to accept your answer since it's the one that actually answers the question. It's my mistake to ask such a siderailed question that it didn't help that much. :)

Comment: As a user, if I click 'log out' I assume that ends my authentication on the server and I would have to log in again to do anything. But if I understand what you're saying, if somebody got hold of their token, they could access the account even though the user thinks they've made it secure?

Answer (score 1):

Try fetching all authenticated users, then check if the target user is among them or not:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.utils import timezone

def get_all_logged_in_users_ids():
    # Query all non-expired sessions
    # use timezone.now() instead of datetime.now() in latest versions of Django
    sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
    uid_list = []

    # Build a list of user ids from that query
    for session in sessions:
        data = session.get_decoded()
        uid_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    return uid_list

class SendMessage(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        m = self.request.data['msg']
        if (self.request.data['user'] in get_all_logged_in_users_ids()):
            # Send message
        else:
            # Don't send message
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723052/how-to-get-the-list-of-the-authenticated-users).

Comment: Because I already know that the current user is authenticated. I want to know if the other user is authenticated as well.

Comment: Ah Ok, got it, I will remove my answer then.

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: Your solution hits the database three times per `targetUser`, it first fetches the user, then all the sessions, and finally filters the users again. It seems really ineffective.

Comment: I updated thy answer, now it hits the database only once.

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood what `is_authenticated` is checking.

Remember that the web is a stateless environment. There is no server-level 'logged-in' status: the only record of whether a user is logged in or not is whether the cookie exists on that user's machine.

Since it is always possible for the user to close their browser, or turn of their machine, without notifying the server, there is no reliable way to know whether or not a user is really logged in. The only way you can approach that is to have some kind of repeated Ajax call every few seconds, posting to a view that updates the user's record with the current time. Then you can check that the user did indeed update within the last few seconds. This won't be totally reliable, though.

Alternatively you can look into using some kind of long-polling system to keep a channel open.

Comment: Whether it's called authentication or something else, I pretty much just need to know if the user has clicked "log out" on their mobile app or not.

Comment: And what happens when they click log out? Don't you care if they just close the app and never use it again - will you just count that as being logged in?

Comment: The auth token gets removed. I was just wondering if there's a way to check that without an extra query for every message.